# Running ApsctJ in Intellij IDEA with Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, aspectj, sbt-aspectj

I am using **Intellij IDEA Community Edition 14.0.3** for Scala development. I am having AspectJ in my application. I am using `sbt-aspect` v0.10.1. 
I am able to run everything fine when I run the application from SBT console. However, when I use **run** from the intellij menu, it is not invoking the aspect. 
Because of this, I am not able to run in Debug Mode. How can I make it work with intellij ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. 
My workaround is:

- Open project Run/Debug configuration on IntelliJ IDEA
- In the *VM Options* field type: `-javaagent:path/to/aspectjweaver.jar`

  *path/to/aspectjweaver.jar* in my case is `C:\Users\aelkin\.ivy2\cache\org.aspectj\aspectjweaver\jars\aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Actually I do not use Scala in IntelliJ IDEA, but Java. Anyway, a quick web search led me to the [SBT Community Plugins](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Community-Plugins.html) page which lists these links:

> ### Plugins for IDEs
>
> #### IntelliJ IDEA
>
> - sbt Plugin to generate IDEA project configuration: https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea
> - IDEA Plugin to embed an sbt Console into the IDE: https://github.com/orfjackal/idea-sbt-plugin

At the time of writing this GitHub is [down for database maintenance](https://status.github.com/), so I cannot check on the projects mentioned there, but in 15 minutes or you should be able to navigate there by yourself and see if the repos actually contain something useful for you.